# Spark Dataframe - cannot resolve ... given

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I was trying to create a data frame in Spark 1.6.0.
I used this command to create it:-

```scala
val df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("header","true")
  .option("delimiter",",")
  .option("inferSchema","true")
  .load("/user/rohitchopra32_gmail/Project1_dataset_bank-full(2).csv")
```

It created a data frame but when I try using `df.show()` command it shows incomplete and unformatted data like this [image: error]
and also when i tried to select data using `val selectedData = df.select("age")`
command it shows me error [image: selected data error]

Link to my data set : -[data set](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwTgYzZKuzAZMmlfZmNoeWxIZVE/view?usp=sharing)

I am new to spark and I don't know what cause this error .
am I missing something?

Comment: Shouldn't the delimiter be `;`?

Comment: yes I too agree with @Psidom

Comment: no it does not change anything

Comment: is it because of the version of spark? i am using 1.6.0

Comment: That CSV that you have shared isn't well formated...

Comment: can you give me example how it should be formatted?

Comment: `"age;""job"";""marital"";""education"";""default"";""balance"";""housing"";""loan"";""contact"";""day"";""month"";""duration"";""campaign"";""pdays"";""previous"";""poutcome"";""y"""` Look at the quotes and at the `;` they are not the same on all your entry

Comment: "age;""job""... should be `"age";"job";` per example...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152451/discussion-between-eliasah-and-rohit-chopra).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I said in the comment, your CSV file is not well formatted, so let's rewrite it and parse it:

```
scala> sc.textFile(filePath).map(x => x.replaceAll("\"", "")).saveAsTextFile("./Downloads/clean_data")
```

Now that we have removed those trailing double quotes that are causing us trouble, we can load the CSV using the line of code that you have :

```
scala> sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header","true").option("delimiter",";").option("inferSchema","true").load("./Downloads/clean_data").show
+---+-------------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+----+--------+---+-----+--------+--------+-----+--------+--------+---+
|age|          job| marital|education|default|balance|housing|loan| contact|day|month|duration|campaign|pdays|previous|poutcome|  y|
+---+-------------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+----+--------+---+-----+--------+--------+-----+--------+--------+---+
| 53|      unknown| married|  unknown|     no|      0|     no|  no|cellular| 25|  aug|     209|       5|   -1|       0| unknown| no|
| 51|   technician| married| tertiary|     no|     -3|     no|  no|cellular| 25|  aug|      91|       9|   -1|       0| unknown| no|
| 33|   technician|  single|secondary|     no|    -32|     no|  no|cellular| 25|  aug|     196|      12|   -1|       0| unknown| no|
| 48|   management|divorced| tertiary|     no|      0|     no|  no|cellular| 25|  aug|     110|       3|   -1|       0| unknown| no|
| 60|      retired| married|  primary|     no|    155|     no|  no|cellular| 25|  aug|     115|       7|   -1|       0| unknown| no|
| 50|   management|divorced| tertiary|     no|      0|     no|  no|cellular| 25|  aug|      57|       3|   -1|       0| unknown| no|
| 59|  blue-collar| married|  primary|     no|   6271|    yes|  no|cellular| 25|  aug|     102|       5|   -1|       0| unknown| no|
| 33|   technician|  single| tertiary|     no|    137|     no|  no|cellular| 25|  aug|      88|       4|   -1|       0| unknown| no|
| 37|self-employed| married|secondary|     no|    119|     no|  no|cellular| 25|  aug|      68|       4|   -1|       0| unknown| no|
| 45|  blue-collar| married|  primary|     no|    185|     no|  no|cellular| 25|  aug|      78|       4|   -1|       0| unknown| no|
| 47|   management| married|secondary|     no|   1083|     no|  no|cellular| 25|  aug|     141|       4|   -1|       0| unknown| no|
| 41|   technician| married|secondary|     no|   2039|     no|  no|cellular| 25|  aug|     160|       4|   -1|       0| unknown| no|
| 52|   management| married| tertiary|     no|    967|     no|  no|cellular| 25|  aug|     472|      10|   -1|       0| unknown| no|
| 35|   technician|  single| tertiary|     no|    275|    yes|  no|cellular| 25|  aug|      63|       5|   -1|       0| unknown| no|
| 34|   technician| married|secondary|     no|     47|     no|  no|cellular| 25|  aug|     132|       6|   -1|       0| unknown| no|
| 36|   management| married| tertiary|     no|   1235|     no|  no|cellular| 25|  aug|      85|       6|   -1|       0| unknown| no|
| 32|   technician| married|secondary|    yes|      4|    yes| yes|cellular| 25|  aug|     132|       8|   -1|       0| unknown| no|
| 36|   management| married| tertiary|     no|   3874|     no|  no|cellular| 25|  aug|     425|       6|   -1|       0| unknown| no|
| 58|  blue-collar| married|  unknown|     no|      9|     no|  no|cellular| 25|  aug|      50|      23|   -1|       0| unknown| no|
| 43|   technician| married|secondary|     no|    136|     no|  no|cellular| 25|  aug|     363|       7|   -1|       0| unknown|yes|
+---+-------------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+----+--------+---+-----+--------+--------+-----+--------+--------+---+
only showing top 20 rows
```

Comment: It just removes the double quotes from all the lines since it's the source of your issue. Then it saves it on disk.

Comment: OFC considering the file that you have shared with us.

Comment: I never thought " should be a problem . +1 from my side. I am wondering why it passed in mine without removing the " commas?

Comment: I can't tell... :-/